# how to convert string to Address?

Tags: solidity

I want to convert string data to address type.I know that we can directly use address type in the parameters, but for some reason I want to convert it from string to address. 

 **sample code**

```
function check(string _address,string _name,string _password) public returns (string)
{

    address add=address(_address);
   if(!checkUser(add))
    {    
        Useraccnts.push(add)-1;
          Users  storage myuser=users[add];
          myuser.name=_name;
          myuser.password=_password;

        return "true";
    }
    else
    {
        return "false";
    }         

}
```

I got JSON-RPC: internal error while executing this function. so I want to check whether it would be resolved if I change the address to a string. If you know how to resolve the JSON-RPC error please help me out.

```
registerUser: function() { 
    var self = this; 
    var acc=account; 
    var name=document.getElementById("name").value; 
    var password=document.getElementById("password").value; 
    var meta; 
    CoinFlipper.deployed().then(function(instance) { 
        meta = instance; 
        return meta.check.call(acc,name,password).then(function (value) { },
```

I'm using the above function in app.js.

> Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {"id":6,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32603}} at Object.InvalidResponse (app.js:10374)

Comment: I'd recommend to pass `_address` as address instead of string: `function check(address _address,string _name,string _password)` so the parsing is done in the client side.

Comment: Thank you @Ismael! actually, I got JSON-RPC: internal error while executing this function. so I want to check whether it would be resolved if I change the address to a string. If you know how to resolve the JSON-RPC error please help me out.

Comment: What is the error reported? How do you call the `check` function?.

Comment: registerUser: function() {
    var self = this;
    var acc=account;
     var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
     var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
    var meta;
    CoinFlipper.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      meta = instance;
      return  meta.check.call(acc,name,password).then(function (value) {    
  },   I'm using the above function in app.js.Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {"id":6,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32603}}
    at Object.InvalidResponse (app.js:10374)

Comment: You can edit your own question and add the example there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue with your code is that you are making a call, but your function is not constant and modifies the storage, you need to issue a standard transaction for that reason

```
CoinFlipper.deployed().then(function(instance) { 
    meta = instance; 
    return meta.check(acc, name, password); /// <--- without `call`
}).then(function (value) {
});
```

Comment: what is the difference between return meta.check(acc, name, password) and return meta.check(acc, name, password,{from:account,gas:300000});

Comment: If you have more doubts it is better to create a new question, so there's more chances it being answered quickly. The difference is the second one you can specify max gas used and the sender account.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, that's not really recommended.

But if you reallyreally want to do it, have a look at [Converting oraclize result from string to address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11758/converting-oraclize-result-from-string-to-address) (especially the answers which are not abour Oraclize).

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract StringToAddress {

function stringToAddress(string memory _address) public pure returns (address) {
    string memory cleanAddress = remove0xPrefix(_address);
    bytes20 _addressBytes = parseHexStringToBytes20(cleanAddress);
    return address(_addressBytes);
}

function remove0xPrefix(string memory _hexString) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    if (bytes(_hexString).length >= 2 && bytes(_hexString)[0] == '0' && (bytes(_hexString)[1] == 'x' || bytes(_hexString)[1] == 'X')) {
        return substring(_hexString, 2, bytes(_hexString).length);
    }
    return _hexString;
}

function substring(string memory _str, uint256 _start, uint256 _end) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    bytes memory _strBytes = bytes(_str);
    bytes memory _result = new bytes(_end - _start);
    for (uint256 i = _start; i < _end; i++) {
        _result[i - _start] = _strBytes[i];
    }
    return string(_result);
}

function parseHexStringToBytes20(string memory _hexString) internal pure returns (bytes20) {
    bytes memory _bytesString = bytes(_hexString);
    uint160 _parsedBytes = 0;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _bytesString.length; i += 2) {
        _parsedBytes *= 256;
        uint8 _byteValue = parseByteToUint8(_bytesString[i]);
        _byteValue *= 16;
        _byteValue += parseByteToUint8(_bytesString[i + 1]);
        _parsedBytes += _byteValue;
    }
    return bytes20(_parsedBytes);
}

function parseByteToUint8(bytes1 _byte) internal pure returns (uint8) {
    if (uint8(_byte) >= 48 && uint8(_byte) <= 57) {
        return uint8(_byte) - 48;
    } else if (uint8(_byte) >= 65 && uint8(_byte) <= 70) {
        return uint8(_byte) - 55;
    } else if (uint8(_byte) >= 97 && uint8(_byte) <= 102) {
        return uint8(_byte) - 87;
    } else {
        revert(string(abi.encodePacked("Invalid byte value: ", _byte)));
    }
}
 }
```