# recommended datatype for "data" in ethereum transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, ethereumj, web3-providers

I am sending data with my transaction by using following way

```
var tx = {from: eth.coinbase, to:eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(1, "ether"),data:web3.toHex("Test Data")}

personal.sendTransaction(tx, "password")
```

As we can see I am using simple string in data which is converted to hex,
I have some questions around it

1. Is there any recommended datatype to use it within data field
2. Is there any standard way to put JSON data in that data field.

(note:currently I am sending JSON data by manually converting the data to JSON string by following way
`data:web3.toHex("{\"key1\":\"Data1\",\"key2\":\"Data2\"}"))`

Answer (score 2):

Encoding a JSON string does not seem like a good idea. See [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6121/parse-json-in-solidity).

Instead of supplying an object as data, you should define your contract function to take the relevant inputs (such as `function f(string key1, uint key2){}`) and use a transaction library such as ethereumjs-tx to compute the data according to your parameters. [Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/how-to-call-my-contracts-function-using-sendtransaction) is an example with only Web3.

Comment: According to this the data is stored in contract storage, But I want to store data on blockchain as a transaction,  eg. If we take example of office assets management, If I get new mouse from hardware guy, I should be stored on block chain, what is the best way to do that.

Comment: Storing data as a transaction is an interesting idea, but the standard way is to store it in a contract. It will be more easily accessible. You will only need the contract address and ABI. To restore data from a tx. hash (or receipt) you will probably need a more complex and specialized software.

Comment: Any special software was not needed, you can get a hash in **input** field of transaction data and convert it to ASCII to get the input fields, But the only major problem is, the data field in transaction will accept only string data There is example of transaction `var tx = {from: eth.coinbase, to:eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(10, "ether"),data:web3.toHex("D1:Testing Data")}`

Comment: can you suggest me any good example of storing data in contract storage which suites the above asset management use case

Comment: The data field is usually the RLP encoding of the function name, parameter names and values. Any basic contract call example will do. You cannot just hex-encode `"name: value"` and put it as data. If you do, your contract needs to do a complex parsing, that's what I called special software.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so what I understand from this discussion is, we should store data in contract instead of transaction, If I got you right, can you suggest any link to example of how to store data in contract

Comment: It's as simple as defining a variable and assigning a value to it. A variable can be a primitive data type, a struct, an array or a combination of those. I think any Solidity example will have these. Check this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/where-can-i-find-some-solidity-smart-contract-source-code-examples).

Comment: I think, I am still confused with this need to retro my understanding, BTW thanks for really good explanation