# Parsing msg.data to extract JSON

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

I get `msg.data` as JSON. How can I parse it in my contract to create variables in my contract with given values?

Comment: The answers to this two-year-old question might help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6121/parse-json-in-solidity  Also, here is a more recent article on this topic: https://steemit.com/json/@chrisdotn/a-json-parser-for-solidity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be less expensive to parse the JSON **outside** the EVM and send the extracted values as parameters to your contract, if that is at all feasible in your design.

Comment: My exact problem is like this: I need a function to take variable number of arguments. 
Eg. in one call, it is
{
"name" : "xyz",
"age" : 12
}
and in other
{
"company_name" : "pqr",
"address" : "some_address"
}
If I get the data via the msg.data then I need to parse it. Other option is to use `mapping` but seems it is not possible as function argument.

Comment: Then, check out the JSON parser described in the Steemit article linked in my previous comment ( https://steemit.com/json/@chrisdotn/a-json-parser-for-solidity ). I have not used it but I read the article and it looks like what you need.